# May the go compiler reorder following code?

Tags: go, concurrency, happens-before, data-race

Lately, I found some code looks like this:

```
var m map[int]int

func writem() {
    tmpm := make(map[int]int)
    for i := 0; i < 4000000; i++ {
        tmpm[i] = i + 10
    }
    m = tmpm
}

func readm() {
    for k, v := range m {
        _, _ = k, v
    }
}

func main() {
    writem()
    go readm()
    writem()
}
```

This program runs fine, but I think the `writem` function body may be reordered by moving `m = tmpm` before the for loop, because this doesn't change the behavior within this goroutine. And this reordering will cause the `concurrent map read and map write` problem. As the [Go Memory Model](https://golang.org/ref/mem) says:

> compilers and processors may reorder the reads and writes executed within a single goroutine only when the reordering does not change the behavior within that goroutine as defined by the language specification

Any I right, or it is safe to write code like this?

Comment: That blurb you quoted doesn't apply to your situation, since the reads and writes are _not_ in the same goroutine. So I don't really understand your question.

Answer (score 7):

> This program runs fine.

No, it doesn't.

---

The results of the program are undefined. You have a data race on map `m`.

```
$ go run -race racer.go
==================
WARNING: DATA RACE
Write at 0x000000510fa0 by main goroutine:
  main.writem()
      /home/peter/gopath/src/racer.go:10 +0xa7
  main.main()
      /home/peter/gopath/src/racer.go:22 +0x4c

Previous read at 0x000000510fa0 by goroutine 13:
  [failed to restore the stack]

Goroutine 13 (finished) created at:
  main.main()
      /home/peter/gopath/src/racer.go:21 +0x47
==================
Found 1 data race(s)
exit status 66
$
```

`racer.go`:

```
package main

var m map[int]int

func writem() {
    tmpm := make(map[int]int)
    for i := 0; i < 4000000; i++ {
        tmpm[i] = i + 10
    }
    m = tmpm
}

func readm() {
    for k, v := range m {
        _, _ = k, v
    }
}

func main() {
    writem()
    go readm()
    writem()
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/OcWmK7ioMkD

---

Reference: [Go: Data Race Detector](https://golang.org/doc/articles/race_detector.html)